# QML: How to add shadow to all menus?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I need to add shadows to all menus in my application. I know how to add a shadow to one menu:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        MenuItem {
            text: "Menu item 1"
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Menu item 2"
        }
        Menu {
            id: subMenu
            title: "Sub menu"
            MenuItem {
                text: "Sub menu item 1"
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: "Sub menu item 2"
            }
        }
    }

    DropShadow
    {
        width: contextMenu.width;
        height: contextMenu.height;
        x: contextMenu.x
        y: contextMenu.y
        visible: contextMenu.visible;

        source: contextMenu.background;

        horizontalOffset: 0;
        verticalOffset: 5;
        radius: 10;
        samples: 7;
        color: "black";
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        onClicked: {
            contextMenu.popup()
        }
    }

}
```

But in this case, a shadow is not added to the submenu. Also I do not want to duplicate DropShadow for every menu in my application. I want to create a MenuWithShadow item and use it instead Menu item.

Is it possible to create MenuWithShadow item? How it can be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I could think of, is through customizing background item of Menu. Here is a simple Menu with glow:

Assume we have MenuWithGlow file:

```
Menu{
    background: Rectangle {
        id: bgRectangle
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40
        border.color: "black"

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow{
            width: bgRectangle.width
            height: bgRectangle.height
            x: bgRectangle.x
            y: bgRectangle.y
            visible: bgRectangle.visible

            source: bgRectangle

            horizontalOffset: 0
            verticalOffset: 5
            radius: 10
            samples: 7
            color: "#000000"
        }
    }
}
```